# One error when I run my R code about .stan file

Tags: r

I execute a code in R as following

```
 model <- rstan::stan_model('ex_05_13.stan')
```

But there is an error as following:

`Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) :  sh: c:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/g++: No such file or directorymake: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.2/etc/x64/Makeconf:229: file492c7acd69ff.o] Error 127`

In addition: Warning message:
`In system(paste(CXX, ARGS), ignore.stdout = TRUE, ignore.stderr = TRUE) : '-E' not found Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection`

My ex_05_13.stan is syntactically correct. I don`t know why I cannot run my ".stan"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Face similar problem... Looks like a folder had previously made so the new R Tools cannot be installed and run the program properly